# How to determine which members to implement while conforming to a protocol in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm learning Swift by playing around with Swift collections. I wanted to create my own Sequence and I know to that I have to conform to `SequenceType` protocol.

How should I know which members of the protocol do I have to implement? Apple documentation shows a lot of methods for the `SequenceType` protocol (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html), eg. `dropLast(_:Int)`, `generate()`, `underestimateCount()`, etc.

But it turns out that I only have to provide `generate()` method and the compiler is happy:

```
class MySequence : SequenceType {
    func generate() -> MyGenerator{
        return MyGenerator(total: 6)
    }
}
```

(if not the various blog posts I wouldn't know which of the `SequenceType` members have to be implemented)

How to determine which member needs to be implemented while conforming to a protocol?

I've seen that some methods are marked with the `Default implementation` tag. But, for instance, the `dropLast(_: Int) -> Self.SubSequence` is not marked with such tag and I don't have to implement it.

Comment: I'm guessing the ones not marked with `Default implementation`?

Comment: @Stefan: I've updated the question. Then what about the `dropLast(_:Int) -> Self.SubSequence` method?

Comment: Updated my answer to address this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the API documentation, you'll notice that some of the methods are marked with `Default implementation`. This means that the implementation for that method has been defined in an extension, and as such, you don't need to override them unless you want to modify the default behavior. The reason this doesn't work for `generate()`, which has default implementations, is because its default implementations have generic constraints that prevent them from handling all cases.

The ones for `underestimateCount()` and the other methods you mentioned have a default implementation without constraints, meaning you do not need to override them.

For `dropLast(_: Int)` specifically, it actually does have a version specified with Default implementation, namely `dropLast(_: Int) -> AnySequence<Self.Generator.Element> Default Implementation`. Even though they're separate in the API docs, this method will suffice since it has the same parameter signature as the required method in the protocol.

Comment: Then how do you explain that the `dropLast(_: Int) -> Self.SubSequence` method is not marked with the `Default implementation` and I don't have to implement it?

Comment: It actually does have a version specified with `Default implementation`, namely `dropLast(_: Int) -> AnySequence<Self.Generator.Element>
 Default Implementation`. Even though they're separate in the API docs, this method will suffice since they have the same parameter signature.

Comment: I get it now, thanks. I'm a Swift newbie, so I thought that they're separate because of their return types and that the one with `Self.SubSequence` needs its *own* implementation